# Way for my texture to emit light/glow on the Eevee engine

Tags: texturing, light

So, im working right now on a scene which ends with this red Ruby, im tryning to find a way for it to glow but keeping all its details, already went with the alpha map trick but doesnt get the finish version i want, its there a step im missing or there's another form??

[image: Object in question, im trying to keep the edge details of the ruby]

Answer (score 0):

In Eevee you have a very fast bloom function:
[image]
However that makes everything pixel bloom as long as it's brighter than the threshold. If you want to make single objects bloom you need to mask them some way and then use the mask for a glow effect in the compositor (post render). One way is to use object pass index.